# Updating to the latest Yocto version sanity.bbclass issues

Tags: python, linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have taken over a project which was using Yocto Fido version from 2015. I need to update this to the latest stable version Thud.

I have cloned the Poky-Thud repository and cloned the latest layers which are required by our customized layer such as meta-openembedded etc. and added our customized layer back to it.

Now, I wasn't expecting this to build straight away without issues by any means, but the below errors I'm getting with the new layers, I just don't understand. There are more errors like this relating to not enough values, but posted below is one.

There is an interface issue in meta/classes/sanity.bbclass. I can't just revert to the older version of meta to solve this, nor I don't think it makes sense to modify the code myself? Any ideas why this is and how to solve it?

```
ERROR: Execution of event handler 'config_reparse_eventhandler' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/new-repo/poky-thud/build- 
bbgw/../meta/classes/sanity.bbclass", line 971, in 
config_reparse_eventhandler(e=<bb.event.ConfigParsed object at 
0x7ff4103bf3c8>):
     python config_reparse_eventhandler() {
    >    sanity_check_conffiles(e.data)
     }
  File "/home/ubuntu/new-repo/poky-thud/build- 
bbgw/../meta/classes/sanity.bbclass", line 572, in sanity_check_conffiles(d= 
<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7ff4108d35c0>):
         for func in funcs:
    >        conffile, current_version, required_version, func = 
func.split(":")
             if check_conf_exists(conffile, d) and d.getVar(current_version) 
is not None and \
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

Comment: 1. make sure you've installed all the build dependencies; 2. delete `tmp` folder.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Build dependencies as in the dependency layers, layers that other layers depend on? I have deleted the tmp folder also. The only thing in my build directory in the beginning before the build starts is the conf folder

Comment: no, host machine ones: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#required-packages-for-the-build-host

Comment: it is trying to upgrade your config customization, while it should go smoothly but it is not expected to  jump from really old version to latest, it usually works from previous releases to next. So my suggestion is that you move conf/ folder to conf.old and let it create a new one. Then transplant the needed changes you made into the newly created local.conf and friends.

Comment: @Khem How does it create a new conf folder? I renamed the other one to conf.old but it throws an error then that there is no conf folder. I tried also to rename the conf/local.conf file just , but it still complains

Comment: You can execute [bitbake-layers create-layer](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-your-own-general-layer) then copy the new conf folder into your existing layer.

Comment: @Engineer999 I was hoping you are using `source ./oe-init-build-env` to do your build environment setup. If you are using something else then you have to manually recreate the files which are compatible with new release and then transplant your changes

Comment: @Khem I was using my own script to set the variables etc. , but used that one to create a new conf folder as you said. Unfortunately I have tonnes of other issues now. It's clear to me that updating a Yocto-based project which was using an old version from 2015, to the latest version is far from an easy task. It just may not be possible in my case

Comment: @Engineer999 I think it will be doable if you use default environment script to create new set of local.conf and other conf files and then transplant your custom changes from previous build on top. Then you can keep going.

Comment: @Khem I've done this for the build/conf files. Do you mean for every layer?

Comment: Just for top level conf files